# The token resolver is unable to resolve the security key reference

Tags: c#, wcf, wif

I am using Windows identification foundation in my project. I am using two certificates for that in my application. one is STS certificate and other is for WCF service project.

I am using SimpleWebTokenHandler for token. 
But  this.Configuration.IssuerTokenResolver.ResolveSecurityKey(clause) throws error: The token resolver is unable to resolve the security key reference

Stack Trace as follows:

> [SecurityTokenValidationException: Symmetric key issue. Error isThe
>   token resolver is unable to resolve the security key reference
>   'NRWA.Business.Token.SimpleWebTokenKeyIdentifierClause'.]
>   NRWA.Business.Token.SimpleWebTokenHandler.WriteToken(XmlWriter writer,
>   SecurityToken token) in
>   e:\Projects\NRWA\SourceCode\NRWA\WebApplication\NRWA.Business\Token\SimpleWebTokenHandler.cs:410
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSerializerAdapter.WriteTokenCore(XmlWriter
>   writer, SecurityToken token) +407
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.WriteRSTRXml(XmlWriter
>   writer, String elementName, Object elementValue,
>   WSTrustSerializationContext context, WSTrustConstantsAdapter
>   trustConstants) +791
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.WriteKnownResponseElement(RequestSecurityTokenResponse
>   rstr, XmlWriter writer, WSTrustSerializationContext context,
>   WSTrustResponseSerializer responseSerializer, WSTrustConstantsAdapter
>   trustConstants) +450
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.WriteKnownResponseElement(RequestSecurityTokenResponse
>   rstr, XmlWriter writer, WSTrustSerializationContext context) +179
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.WriteResponse(RequestSecurityTokenResponse
>   response, XmlWriter writer, WSTrustSerializationContext context,
>   WSTrustResponseSerializer responseSerializer, WSTrustConstantsAdapter
>   trustConstants) +344
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.WriteXml(RequestSecurityTokenResponse
>   response, XmlWriter writer, WSTrustSerializationContext context) +243 
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationSerializer.GetResponseAsString(RequestSecurityTokenResponse
>   response, WSTrustSerializationContext context) +227
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.SignInResponseMessage..ctor(Uri
>   baseUrl, RequestSecurityTokenResponse response, WSFederationSerializer
>   federationSerializer, WSTrustSerializationContext context) +101
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInRequest(SignInRequestMessage
>   requestMessage, IPrincipal principal, SecurityTokenService sts,
>   WSFederationSerializer federationSerializer) +375
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessRequest(HttpRequest
>   request, IPrincipal principal, SecurityTokenService sts, HttpResponse
>   response, WSFederationSerializer federationSerializer) +1435
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessRequest(HttpRequest
>   request, IPrincipal principal, SecurityTokenService sts, HttpResponse
>   response) +18    PassiveSTS._Default.Page_PreRender(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   e:\Projects\NRWA\SourceCode\NRWA\WebApplication\NRWA.STS\Default.aspx.cs:30
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4297